# Volume through integration

Tags: calculus, volume

$y=x^2$ and $y=12 - 2x^2$ intersect at the points $(-2,4)$ and $(2,4)$. The region bounded by the curves and the $y$-axis is rotated about the $y$-axis. By splitting the shading region into two parts, or otherwise, find the volume of the solid formed.

When I draw it, the shaded area is on right side of the y-axis and above the x-axis)

I got $24\pi$ but I'm certain its wrong please show full working.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: In particular could you explain how you got the $24\pi$.

Comment: Did you mean $(-2,4)$?

Comment: I also got 24pi. I can give my method but as you are certain that its wrong I think I am not doing it correctly.

Comment: Did you use (-2,4) and (2,4) or (2,4) and (2,4)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly draw a clear diagram.

[image]

The volume of revolution around the y-axis is given by:

$$\pi\int_{y_1}^{y_2}x^2dy$$

Your curve has two distinct areas so work out each separately:

$$\pi\left(\int_0^4x_1^2dy+\int_4^{12}x_2^2dy\right)$$

Note that the limits used are the y-values as that is the axes we are integrating around.

Next rearrange the equations into the form $x^2=...$ and substitute in:

$$\pi\left(\int_0^4ydy+\int_4^{12}\left(6-\frac{y}{2}\right)dy\right)$$

$$=\pi\left(\left[\frac{y^2}{2}\right]_0^4+\left[6y-\frac{y^2}{4}\right]_4^{12}\right)$$

$$=\pi\left(\frac{4^2}{2}-0+6\cdot12-\frac{12^2}{4}-\left(6\cdot4-\frac{4^2}{4}\right)\right)$$

$$=24\pi\space units^3$$

Comment: WOW, you have explained this perfectly. I can now apply my new-found knowledge on the rest of these equations. Thanks you so much!

Comment: However, when you rearrange y=12-2x^2 doesnt it rearrange to x^2=6-y/2?

Comment: Good catch. I'll update my answer. Sorry.

Comment: Awesome, again, thanks so much.